# find or create user using passport and mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate users with OAuth2, GitHub, and using passport to do that.

I have a very simple User model purely for testing purposes.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true }
});
mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

The routes are more or less straight from passport's documentation.

```
router.get("/github", passport.authenticate("GitHub", { scope: ["user"] }));
router.get("/github/callback", passport.authenticate("GitHub", {
    successRedirect: "/#/user/authenticated",
    failureRedirect: "/#/auth/error"
}));
```

After serializeUser and deserializeUser, I have the following:

```
passport.use('GitHub', new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
    clientID: 'client id',
    clientSecret: 'too secret for you to handle',
    callbackURL: 'http://dev.corvid.com:3000/auth/github/callback'
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: profile.id },                  // what to query for 
      { $set: { email: profile.email } },   // the update arguments
      { new: true, upsert: true},           // the options
    function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

However, I can't seem to quite get this to work as intended. It directs me to authenticate on github, which I accept. Then I am redirected back to my site to get the following message:

```
{"message":"Cast to string failed for value \"undefined\" at path \"email\""}
```

A quick console.log shows that the profile is an empty object `{}`.

How should I manage upserting users and authenticating for OAuth2 with passport on a single page app?

EDIT: url on the last page looks like this: `http://dev.corvid.com:3000/auth/github/callback?code=xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work

```
var passport       = require("passport");
var GitHubStrategy = require("passport-github").Strategy;
var mongoose       = require("mongoose");
var User           = mongoose.model("User");

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  var query   = { githubId: user.id };
  var update  = { $set: {
    githubId: user.id,
    name: user.displayName,
    avatarUrl: user._json.avatar_url,
    profile: user._json
  }};
  var options = { new: true, upsert: true };
  User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, u) {
    return done(err, u);
  });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.find({ "githubId": id }, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: 'identification',
    clientSecret: 'too secret to handle',
    callbackURL: 'http://dev.corvid.me:3000/auth/github/callback'
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));
```